# How to remove digits after decimal in Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am working with TSV file.

In Column 1 I have entries like

> ENSG00000228232.1

I want to convert this into

> ENSG00000228232

How can I perform this operation in bulk?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in cell B1 and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1;SEARCH(".";A1)-1);A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps select "Column 1" and Edit > Find & Replace...

Find `\..+`, Replace nothing, using `Other options` of `Current selection only` and `Regular expressions`.